# loop through jstree to search for all occurences of a node id and then change the class of those nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have the following javascript code which changes the class (of the `<ins>` tag) for each selected node in the jstree:

```
   $j("#actionButton1").click(function() {

      $j.each($j("#demo2").jstree("get_selected"), function(index, element) {

      alert($j(element).attr('id'));

      var sub_id = $j(element).attr('id'); //node id is stored in the varialble sub_id

      $j("#"+sub_id+" ins:eq(1)").attr("class","jstree-icon2"); // set class to display new icon

   });//end of selected nodes loop
});
```

The code above works fine except for one thing, if the selected sub_id exists in more than one place in the tree, the class to display a new icon does not seem to work.

I believe i have loop through the jstree to search for all occurences of the sub_id and then associate the new class to the nodes.

Any hint on how to do that is most welcomed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would recommend making all id attribute values unique to start as they are not meant to be repeated.

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicated sud_ids, this is a problem in the generation of your code.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the name or class attributes instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion but i am retrieving that id from the db and i cannot avoid the dupicates

Comment: Yes, i think i am going to change the wording to something like data-subid

Comment: @tanya instead what I was suggesting to use either the name or class attributes instead of the id attribute. The id attribute is intended to be unique. Additionally, if you are just using an integer I would recommend prefixing that as well to save any chance of conflicts with other enties.

Comment: alright, am going to replace the id attri with the name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the # id selector it will only return the first element. Adding sub_id to a name or class attribute should help you with your problem. As i mentioned in the comment, the id attribute should be unique on the page.

You will also want to remove the `:eq(1)` from your selector if you want to apply the class to all matching elements and not just the second. `:eq` accepts a 0 based index.

**Edit**

Your new selector:

```
$j("your-element[name='"+sub_id+"' ins").attr("class","jstree-icon2");
```

Comment: @tanya I've updated my answer to include the new selector if you want to select ALL ins elements under your-element with the name attribute of sub_id

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the node directly instead of using the ID as a selector:

```
$j('#actionButton1').click(function() {
    $j.each($j('#demo2').jstree('get_selected'), function(index, element) {
        $j('ins:eq(1)', element).addClass('jstree-icon2');
    });
});
```

As mentioned in the comments above, IDs should be unique.

I hope this helps!