# How to loop over all the nodes of a jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, jstree-search, jstree-dnd

I am unable to figure out how I can loop over all the nodes of a jstree.

What I am looking for is that for the jstree `jstree1`. I want to loop over all of its children and sub-children and print/get the `id` of each leaf.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript implementation of a depth first search or a breadth first search? Could you provide a link that describes what jstree is?

Comment: Did you check this question here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010636/loop-through-jstree-to-search-for-all-occurences-of-a-node-id-and-then-change-th

Comment: Yes. but here they check `get_selected` but in my case no node is selected. I just want to loop over the tree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296410/jstree-how-to-get-all-nodes-from-jstree

Comment: Please see my answer at [jstree jquery how to iterate through all nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44369074/979621).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem

```
$(function () {
    $.each($("#jstree1").jstree('full').find("li"), function (index, element) 
    {
        console.log($(element));
    });
});
```